# Does this part of an arithmetic progression have a name?

Tags: proof-writing

In this arithmetic progression - 11+30w, 11 is the initial term, 30 is the common difference, and w is what? I use the letter w because it is the first letter of the word whole, and I use w to represent the whole numbers. So, 30·0=0. 11+0=11. When w=0, the polynomial equals 11. Did I say that right? I want to say that when the what is 0, the polynomial is 11, however, what is not the right word. Also, I want to be able to describe the polynomial if I were to make a change to the w. I have a mathematical concept, but I need a word to use to explain it.

Comment: w represents the "w"th term.

Comment: $w$ is the number of the term. So if you had $w=2$, it would be the second term. So in general, it's the $w$-th term.

In my opinion, you could just say "When $w$ is $0$, the polynomial is $11$".

Comment: I feel like I need a noun. Suppose I want to replace the w with another arithmetic progression. Example: 11+30(13+30w) The other parts have names. It is a factor. Can I call it the factor? This way, I could describe the new progression as 11+30(f) with the factor being 13+30w.